# Choose the api to use programmatically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I’m developing an app that CRUD orders to external databases. Obviously these databases have different APIs.

I have created an abstraction layer that calls the correct API and is the only thing that will change if databases are added.

This works perfectly, but I’m wondering if there are more efficient ways to do this.

The way I do it now:

Front end:

```
addOrder(orderId,productName, ......)
```

Abstraction layer:

```
let addOrder = (orderId, productName, ......) => {
  if (selectedDatabase == ‘x’) {
    insertOrder(orderId, productName, ......)
  } else {
    AddOrder(orderId, productName, .....)
  }
```

I’m using Vue.js and Vuex and a solution using vuex would be wonderful.

Comment: You can move the database names to configuration file or environment variables. Then refer it here

Comment: @VeluSGautam Yes, although it’s more about the different names of the methods that need to be called than the database names